# When request json and response json is same, wants to create same json object with only updated field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have normal HTML UI to View and Update and used Angular js to call rest services.

I am calling rest service display and update, both services shares same json object say

**Display Response**

```
{
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Address": {
        "city": "XYZCity",
        "Phone": {
            "Mob": 898998888,
            "Tel": 56556
        }
    }
}
```

Now lets say I have updated "Mob" and "city" to 8888888 and ABCCity, I have to send only those updated fields in same update request like.

**Update Request**

```
{
    "Address": {
        "city": "ABCCity",
        "Phone": {
            "Mob": 888888
        }
    }
}
```

is there any way, I can do this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give some context? How do you want to edit these two variables? Input field or line command?

Comment: You can't send _partial_ JSON. Either a new one, or the whole thing.

Comment: is there any simple way to create new one and set it

Comment: Why would you really need to do this nd not send the whole record?

Comment: On submit I am sending this whole object to backend, For each field update they have to call and external service, to avoid external service call of unchanged field I have to do this.

Comment: this is just an example, I have a huge json object

Answer (score -1):

Make the `Name, Tel` as undefined in data object before making the call to API as below.

```
let data = {
    "Name" :"ABC",
    "Address": {
        "city": "XYZCity",
        "Phone": {
            "Mob": 898998888,
            "Tel": 123  
        }
    }
};

data.Name = undefined;
data.Address.Phone.Tel = undefined;
```

`data` object will be sent as below over the network in same request.

```
{
    "Address": {
        "city": "XYZCity",
        "Phone": {
            "Mob": 898998888
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should maintain a shallow copy of the data object. Then before sending the request, compare each member of original data object with its copy and only send those which have changed.

Here is how:

let dataCopy = angular.copy(data);

Make changes to you `data` object.

Then send as below:

```
{
    "Name" : (data.Name !== dataCopy.Name) ? data.Name : undefined
}
```

Comment: This is just an example I have a huge object, for each field I am not going to  set undefined

Comment: you should maintain a shallow copy of the data object. Then before sending the request, compare each member of original data object with its copy and only send those which have changed.

Comment: let us also know if you find a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. But not sure how my answer was incorrect to be marked negative.